# re.RegexObject doesn't exist (raises AttributeError)

Tags: python, regex, monkeypatching

In my latest series of questions, I asked about fooling around with the internals of `argparse`.  Mostly, I want to change an attribute defined as:

```
class FooClass(object):
   def __init__(self):
      self._this_is_a_re=re.compile("foo")
```

Since it is "protected", I would like to check if this attribute exists and if it is a regular expression before I substitute in my own regex.  e.g.:

```
import re
myFoo=FooClass()
attr='_this_is_a_re'
if(hasattr(myFoo,attr) and isinstance(getattr(myFoo,attr),re.RegexObject):
   setattr(myFoo,attr,re.compile("bar"))
```

This fails with an attribute error because re has no attribute named `RegexObject` even though it is in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.RegexObject).  Why is RegexObject documented but not available? What am I supposed to be using there?  I suppose I could say: `type(a) is type(b)`, but that seems ugly...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's `<type '_sre.SRE_Pattern'>` but I'd simply use `type(re.compile(''))`.

BTW, it appears that even `re` developers don't know for sure what the exact type is, as seen [here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/412c7daed0db/Lib/re.py#l222):

```
_pattern_type = type(sre_compile.compile("", 0))
```

Comment: Yeah, I can see that ... but why is the type something prefixed by an underscore when `re.RegexObject` is what we always refer to in the documentation?  and `isinstance(a,_sre.SRE_Pattern)` also doesn't work.  `isinstance(a,re._pattern_type)` does work.

Comment: Looks like we're converging on the same idea -- I arrived at it by trial and error and looking at the output of `dir` -- Checking the source is probably a better approach.